# Javascript: Going to root url (to avoid relative url)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, url, url-routing

I'm having an issue with urls.

I have a navbar.ejs file that I include in every page of my website via

```
<% include ./navbar %>
```

In the file, I have something like this:

```
<li><a id="loginButton" href="../login">Login</a></li>
<li><a id="signupButton" href="../users/new">Sign up</a></li>
```

The issue I'm having is that depending on where I am on the website, the login button might or might not work. This is because of

"../login"

So at times when you click the login button, you're directed to
https://baseurl/login

At other times, it goes to
https://baseurl/campgrounds/login
This URL is wrong and doesn't exist.

I know the source of the problem obviously. But how do I get replace "../login" with an absolute URL path... As in, how do I go back to the root?

Something like
$("#loginButton).attr("href", document.location.hostname + "/login") doesn't work because it just directs to
baseurl/baseurl/login
which is also invalid

Comment: Just `href="/login"` will be enough.

Comment: ``$("#loginButton).attr("href", "http://" + document.location.hostname + "/login")`` also a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the URL of the login page will always be https://yelpcamp-asool.c9users.io/login then the below code will work fine.

```
<a id="loginButton" href="/login">
```